# Is std::views::values supposed to work with std::map?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

The C++20 ranges library includes some (in my opinion) amazing features. For example I really started to like the [`std::views::keys`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view) and [`std::views::values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/values_view) range adaptors, that simplify iterating over the keys or values of a map. While previously one needed to do something like

```
std::map<int, int> m {{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}};
...
for ( auto&& e : m ) {
    auto v = e.second;
    // use v
}
```

With C++20 you can do the same a lot more elegantly:

```
for ( auto v : std::views::values(m) ) {
    // use v
}
```

At least, that is what I though was possible and probably an intended use case of `std::views::values`. I recently discovered that clang-14/13/12 does not compile the second version in contrast to gcc-12/11/10 and msvc-19.32 ([overview on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1fd7M3crn)).

What am I missing here? Is the code above valid C++20 or is clang right about refusing to compile it?

Edit:
I also noticed, that clang does not consider `std::map` to be a `std::ranges::viewable_range`. But I do not see why clangs `std::map` should behave different from gcc's `std::map` in a standard library function.

Comment: The clang-cl compiler in VS2022 compiles your second version without problem.

Comment: This is probably due to clang not yet implementing all features of C++20 needed for this example

Comment: Clang doesn't support libstdc++'s `<ranges>` at all (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72716894/how-to-use-stdviewstransform-on-a-vector), and libc++ hasn't implemented `std::views::values` yet.

Answer (score 0):

The [cppreference page on `std::views::values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/values_view) shows this usecase: a `std::map<char, int>` being piped into `std::views::values`.

Furthermore, it explicitly says

> **Note**
>
> `values_view` can be useful for extracting values from associative containers, e.g. for (`auto const& value : std::views::values(map)) { /*...*/ }`.

Therefore, if your example doesn't work, it's either a bug or a missing, yet to implement, feature in the compiler.

Unless one thinks that cppreference's **Note** is wrong, which I don't.